# Accessing part of a pandas DataFrame by reference in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a large DataFrame object and I want to access parts of it by reference, that is, in a way that whenever the original, large DataFrame is updated, the smaller ones are also updated.

Creating a copy of the smaller parts does not work for obvious reasons.

```
import pandas as pd

# Create a DataFrame
large_df= pd.DataFrame(dict(a=range(3)))
large_df

0:
   a
0  0
1  1
2  2

# Sample some of the DataFrame indices.
# In this example I keep accessing the even rows of a DataFrame
# while updating it, but `sample` is, in general,
# a random list of rows.
sample=[0,2]

# Create a copy of the sampled part of the DataFrame
sub_df = large_df.loc[sample]
sub_df

1:
   a
0  0
2  2

# Modify the original DataFrame
large_df.loc[:,'b'] = range(3,6)
large_df

2:
   a  b
0  0  3
1  1  4
2  2  5

# The copy of the sampled part is kept unchanged 
sub_df

3:
   a
0  0
2  2
```

The only solution I found is going back to the `loc` statement.

```
# Reusing loc, the sampled part includes the modification
large_df.loc[sample]
4:
   a  b
0  0  3
2  2  5
```

Is there a simpler way?

Comment: You are looking for a subset of the data-frame that acts as a *view*.

Comment: You need read the [doc](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy).Maybe is    
 [copy](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html#pandas-dataframe-copy) what you want

Comment: @ShiheZhang no, they don't want copy, they want a view.

Comment: If you're asking for whether this is possible, the short answer is, no.